# Создать перевернутую таблицу HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сделать так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос. **Как?**

Я так понимаю что это перевернутая таблица HTML.
Где слева это элементы **TH** а справа это строки. Помогите.

Comment: Дивами сделать можно, но сложновато из за динамической высоты продукта, и его описания.

Comment: Почему обязательно TH? Сделайте через CSS
.table tr td:first-child { font-wright: bold; }

Comment: А представьте если я буду нажимать на правую стрелку на слайдере..
Мне перерисовывать всю таблицу полностью?

Comment: Весьма сложная задача. Рекомендую исследовать плагин `datatables` - встроенного слайдера там нет, но возможность переключения колонок предусмотрена, насколько я помню, там предусмотрена. colreorer кажется.

Comment: Тут не таблицей надо делать. Ставьте слева див с заголовками, справа див с товарами, загоняйте их в слайдер вроде slick. Дизайн явно с точным позиционированием блоков, делается достаточно просто

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется семантичности:

```
<th></th>
```

http://htmlbook.ru/html/th

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Цена</th>
            <td>1,50р</td>
            ...
        </tr>
...

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Пример использования - https://lexnekr.github.io/filmsrating-for-y/ru/full-version.html (именно так, как вы хотите, только 1 колонка)

Но в принципе, как в комментариях и написано, достаточно сделать css правило для 1 столбца, визуально выделяющее их.

Answer (score 0):

@Алексей Задойный все правильно написал. Только смысл отсылать куда-то, когда пример прост как сибирские валенки.

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <th>bla-bla</th>
 <th>bla-bla</th>
 <th>bla-bla</th>
 <th>bla-bla</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <th>bla-bla</th>
 <td>bla-bla</td>
 <td>bla-bla</td>
 <td>bla-bla</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <th>bla-bla</th>
 <td>bla-bla</td>
 <td>bla-bla</td>
 <td>bla-bla</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <th>bla-bla</th>
 <td>bla-bla</td>
 <td>bla-bla</td>
 <td>bla-bla</td>
</tr>
</table>
```